# Parsing JSON in Go

Tags: json, go

I am new to Go, and I am building a web API that uses data from the RDW in my Android Application. However I have trouble parsing JSON in Go, where as in Java I could easily use something like `jsonObject.getString("AreaId")`. It does not seem like I can do this in Go.

I am trying to parse the following JSON to save it in a MySQL database:

```
{
  'd': {
    'results': [
      {
        '__metadata': {
          'id': 'https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/opendata.rdw/StatischParkeren.Open.Data/v1/AREAGEOMETRY(1)',
          'uri': 'https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/opendata.rdw/StatischParkeren.Open.Data/v1/AREAGEOMETRY(1)',
          'type': 'opendata.rdw.StatischParkeren.Open.Data.AREAGEOMETRY'
        },
        'AREAGEOMETRY_ID': 1,
        'AreaManagerId': '34',
        'AreaId': 'ALMBUITEN',
        'EndDateArea': null,
        'StartDateArea': '/Date(1330560000000)/',
        'AreaGeometryTxt': 'POLYGON ((5.2736760005354881 52.391216600313783, 5.2752534225583076 52.392331821843982, 5.2771425843238831 52.391448376700282, 5.2795117920336709 52.392518069183787, 5.2794937640428543 52.392529543489218, 5.2795250192284584 52.392524041235447, 5.2795117920336709 52.392518069183787, 5.27959094196558 52.392467692494392, 5.28429589420557 52.394528595730662, 5.2830820381641388 52.3958012573421, 5.2826158106327057 52.396464187651873, 5.28216527402401 52.396755328401923, 5.2811877280473709 52.396325327456, 5.27938649058342 52.395481485873461, 5.2793451324105263 52.395514352247119, 5.2788525596261024 52.395813956856728, 5.278492659330368 52.39611235447228, 5.2776647135615349 52.396820867434144, 5.2777034044265747 52.396853528916836, 5.2768759876489639 52.397581102326512, 5.274177111685276 52.396415254101157, 5.2741994857788086 52.396424867212772, 5.2686141580343246 52.394008679315448, 5.26860549300909 52.394005045294762, 5.2691666409373283 52.39350445382297, 5.2705547362565994 52.392721636220813, 5.2723518460904533 52.392156438032842, 5.2723518460989 52.39215643890202, 5.272359311580658 52.392154090106487, 5.2723518460904533 52.392156438032842, 5.2723498195409775 52.391947904601693, 5.273051455616951 52.391403153538704, 5.2736760005354881 52.391216600313783))',
        'AreaGeometryGml': '<Polygon xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml"><exterior><LinearRing><posList>5.2736760005354881 52.391216600313783 5.2752534225583076 52.392331821843982 5.2771425843238831 52.391448376700282 5.2795117920336709 52.392518069183787 5.2794937640428543 52.392529543489218 5.2795250192284584 52.392524041235447 5.2795117920336709 52.392518069183787 5.27959094196558 52.392467692494392 5.28429589420557 52.394528595730662 5.2830820381641388 52.3958012573421 5.2826158106327057 52.396464187651873 5.28216527402401 52.396755328401923 5.2811877280473709 52.396325327456 5.27938649058342 52.395481485873461 5.2793451324105263 52.395514352247119 5.2788525596261024 52.395813956856728 5.278492659330368 52.39611235447228 5.2776647135615349 52.396820867434144 5.2777034044265747 52.396853528916836 5.2768759876489639 52.397581102326512 5.274177111685276 52.396415254101157 5.2741994857788086 52.396424867212772 5.2686141580343246 52.394008679315448 5.26860549300909 52.394005045294762 5.2691666409373283 52.39350445382297 5.2705547362565994 52.392721636220813 5.2723518460904533 52.392156438032842 5.2723518460989 52.39215643890202 5.272359311580658 52.392154090106487 5.2723518460904533 52.392156438032842 5.2723498195409775 52.391947904601693 5.273051455616951 52.391403153538704 5.2736760005354881 52.391216600313783</posList></LinearRing></exterior></Polygon>'
      },
      {
        '__metadata': {
          'id': 'https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/opendata.rdw/StatischParkeren.Open.Data/v1/AREAGEOMETRY(2)',
          'uri': 'https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/opendata.rdw/StatischParkeren.Open.Data/v1/AREAGEOMETRY(2)',
          'type': 'opendata.rdw.StatischParkeren.Open.Data.AREAGEOMETRY'
        },
        'AREAGEOMETRY_ID': 2,
        'AreaManagerId': '34',
        'AreaId': 'ALMTEGELZ',
        'EndDateArea': null,
        'StartDateArea': '/Date(1330560000000)/',
        'AreaGeometryTxt': 'POLYGON ((5.216308925 52.370733155, 5.216800447 52.370804276, 5.216837124 52.370755791, 5.217178542 52.370807152, 5.217373999 52.370322534, 5.217353484 52.370319431, 5.217371539 52.370274734, 5.216664547 52.370167441, 5.216571837 52.370396589, 5.216451509 52.370380301, 5.216308925 52.370733155))',
        'AreaGeometryGml': '<Polygon xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/gml"><exterior><LinearRing><posList>5.216308925 52.370733155 5.216800447 52.370804276 5.216837124 52.370755791 5.217178542 52.370807152 5.217373999 52.370322534 5.217353484 52.370319431 5.217371539 52.370274734 5.216664547 52.370167441 5.216571837 52.370396589 5.216451509 52.370380301 5.216308925 52.370733155</posList></LinearRing></exterior></Polygon>'
      },
 ],
    '__next': 'https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/opendata.rdw/StatischParkeren.Open.Data/v1/AREAGEOMETRY?$skiptoken=100'
  }
}
```

This is my code in Go:

```
type Data struct {
    Next string
    Results Result
}

type Result struct {
    Results []AreaGeometry
}

type AreaGeometry struct {
    AREAGEOMETRY_ID int32
    AreaManagerId int64
    AreaId string
    EndDateArea string
    StartDateArea string
    AreaGeometryTxt string
}

// Synchronizes the AreaGeometry in our MySQL database with the AreaGeometry in the database from the RDW
func retrieveData() {
    resp, err := http.Get("https://api.datamarket.azure.com/opendata.rdw/StatischParkeren.Open.Data/v1/AREAGEOMETRY?$format=json")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error()) // TODO: proper error handling
    }
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    var d Data
    json.Unmarshal(body, &d)
    fmt.Println("Next: " + d.Next)
}
```

However, `d.Next` returns an empty string after unmarshaling. What am I doing wrong? What is the Go way of taking care of this?

Comment: ALWAYS check for errors when you can! `err = json.Unmarshal(body, &d)` and print `err`, this will tell you what's wrong.

Comment: Hi, i've changed it to err = json.Unmarshal(body, &d) however err = nil after executing. And fmt.Print(d) gives: { {[]}}.

Comment: Ok for this time, the problem must come from somewhere else, but I assure you it's always better to check for errors anyway ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use JSON annotations (referred to as struct "tags" in the docs) to let it know what the name of the field is in the JSON:

```
type Data struct {
    Next string `json:"__next"` //Field appears in JSON as key "__next".
    Results Result `json:"results"`
}
```

I believe Go automatically takes care of `results` vs `Results`, but if you are going to send data back and want it to be lowercase, you still need the annotation.

Your `Results Result` is incorrect - Results is not an object of type Result, it is an array of AreaGeometry, so it should look like:

```
type Data struct {
    Next string  `json:"__next"` //Field appears in JSON as key "__next".
    Results []AreaGeometry
}
```

Also, you need a wrapper for the D object that is in the JSON:

```
type D struct {
    D Data `json:"d"`
}


func main() {
    body := jsonString //too long to put here, but in the playground. 
    var d D
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(body), &d)
    if (err != nil) {
       fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Next: " + d.D.Next)

}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/yK-zNxEMvy

Comment: for those searching the docs, these annotations are referred to as struct "tags"

Comment: @JimB thanks! I didn't know what they were called, I've updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: @dave the json sample he copy/pasted is invalid, however I manually checked the source and it checks out.

Comment: @OneOfOne I didn't even think to do that, assumed it would require auth or something but looking at the url now that was smart to do

Comment: Thanks, I've got it working now. Sorry for the incorrect sample by the way.